# Golang io.Reader usage with net.Pipe

Tags: go

The problem I'm trying to solve is using io.Reader and io.Writer in a net application without using bufio and strings as per the examples I've been able to find online. For efficiency I'm trying to avoid the memcopys those imply.

I've created a test application using net.Pipe on the play area (https://play.golang.org/p/-7YDs1uEc5). There is a data source and sink which talk through a net.Pipe pair of connections (to model a network connection) and a loopback on the far end to reflect the data right back at us.

The program gets as far as the loopback agent reading the sent data, but as far as I can see the write back to the connection locks; it certainly never completes. Additionally the receiver in the Sink never receives any data whatsoever.

I can't figure out why the write cannot proceed as it's wholly symmetrical with the path that does work. I've written other test systems that use bi-directional network connections but as soon as I stop using bufio and ReadString I encounter this problem. I've looked at the code of those and can't see what I've missed.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is on line 68:

```
data_received := make([]byte, 0, count)
```

This line creates a slice with length 0 and capacity `count`.  The call to `Read` does not read data because the length is 0. The call to `Write` blocks because the data is never read.

Fix the issue by changing the line to:

```
data_received := make([]byte, count)
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/YRZ4H91AUm)

Note that "Finished Writing" may not be printed because the program can exit before `dataSrc` finishes executing.

Comment: Oh, how silly of me. That's muscle memory always initialising a slice to be empty. Thanks very much

Comment: By the way, `io.Copy` is not needed because both `Conn`s returned by `net.Pipe` are connected! Consult [the doc](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Pipe) and try the code without explicit `io.Copy`...